# SQL: Cascade "insert" and insert on update if not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Table A and Table B have "Master-Slave" relationship via a FK on Table B. The key is set up for cascade delete and update.

Table B is new and thus does not have as many records as A.

As Table A is inserted, I want Table B to have a new record with the ID field of Table A completed with everything else blank ready for user input.

As Table A is updated, I want Table B to have a new record with the ID field of Table A completed with everything else blank ready for user input if Table A's ID does not yet exist in Table B.

Triggers, I assume?

Many thanks!

Comment: I give up why would you want to do that? For instance if the user despite you making everything ready to update it, doesn't, what are you going to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use an insert trigger on table A.

whenever you insert into A, check if the ID exists in B and if not, then insert into B.